# SocketException in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, sockets, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

My selenium code is executing successfully on firefox and chrome browsers using selenium latest jars(2.47.1) but I am getting this exception **java.net.SocketException** on the console from last few days.
Please help me and thanks in advance.

My code looks like following and it is working fine:

```
public class testngClass1 {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public static void a() {
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.newtours.demoaut.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        System.out.println("QWERYT");
    }

    @Test
    public static void b() {

        driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("QWERYT");
        System.out.println("QWERYT");
        // driver.quit();
    }
}
```

The stack trace of the exception is:

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
  at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
  at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
  at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1876)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1785)
  at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.<init>(ObjectOutputStream.java:247)
  at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.SerializedMessageSender.sendMessage(SerializedMessageSender.java:20)
  at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.MessageHub.sendMessage(MessageHub.java:44)
  at org.testng.remote.strprotocol.RemoteTestListener.onTestSuccess(RemoteTestListener.java:88)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1800)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1780)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:749)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:846)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1170)
  at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
  at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
  at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1125)
  at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:749)
  at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:317)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:312)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:274)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:223)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:965)
  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:890)
  at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:824)
  at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:110)
  at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:205)
  at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:174)
```

Comment: And your code looks like what?

Comment: From which Line of the code the exception been thrown

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem. I tried with

`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` & it worked for me. To run with that command

right click on the script > Click on Run As > Run Configuration > Arguments > VM Arguments
Add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` > 
Apply > Run

Comment: I tried same, right click on the script an add above line but script doesn't run and showing \"Error: Could not find or load main class Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
"